# Weird deformation with subdivision surface

Tags: modeling, modifiers, subdivision-surface

I'm new to Blender and I'm currently practicing by making a basic low poly character. I've encountered a weird glitch with when I apply subdivision surface to the model.

[image]

Used the boolean modifier to cut out some fingers for my model. However, when I activate the subdivision surface modifier, this happens.
[image]

How do I go about fixing this?

Comment: avoid ngons (faces with more than 4 vertices)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the topology of your hand there. The entire part with the fingers is one big concave n-gon, not good. 
[image: your hand]
The ngon is what is making the subdivision surface freak out.

To fix this you need to change the topology of the fingers so that each finger is a separate face (example below)

[image: hand with better topology] [image: hand withmuch better topology]

Sadly there is no easy to fix for that. I tried using the knife tool and cutting in some [additional faces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYjnF.png), but that just moves the problem ngon, not get rid of it.

Comment: Oh, I see

What's a good way of doing this after the fingers have been cut out? I know I can manually create loops (CTRL+R), but I was just curious if there's any specific tools to help speed up this process.